# Powershell Export to CSV with three coumns

Tags: csv, powershell, invoke-command

function getServerInfo
{
    $serverList = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\list.txt"

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential "username"
foreach($server in $serverList)
{

   $osVersion = gwmi win32_operatingSystem -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
   if($osVersion -eq $null)
   {
        $osVersion = "cannot find osversion"

   }

   $psv = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major} -ErrorAction Ignore

   if($psv -eq $null)
   {

        $psv2 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major} -ErrorAction Ignore
        Write "$server has $($osVersion.Caption)and PSVersion is $psv2"
   }
   else{

     Write "$server has $($osVersion.Caption)and PSVersion is $psv"

   }

}
```

}

I am trying to create a csv file with 3 columns.
First column will have $server, second column will have $osVersion and third will have $psv. Please help. thank you!

Comment: If one of the two answers provided a solution to your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer so that future users can locate it if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the foreach loop, consider using the ForEach-Object cmdlet so that the results can be piped to other commands.  Inside of the ForEach-Object script block, you can calculate the 3 values you need, and then its easy to create CSV string using string interpolation.  The results can then be piped to the appropriate output file.

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Users\username\Desktop\list.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $Server = $_
    $OSVersion = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $PSVersion = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock { $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major }

    "$Server,$OSVersion,$PSVersion"   
} | Out-File outputFilename.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

To export to a CSV using the `Export-CSV` cmdlet, PowerShell expects an array of objects with the same set of properties to output. For your case you can do that fairly simply as such:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential "username"
$AllServers=foreach($server in $serverList)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Server' = $Server
        'osVersion' = gwmi win32_operatingSystem -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select -Expand Caption
        'psv' = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major} -ErrorAction Ignore -Credential $cred
   }

}

$AllServers | Export-Csv c:\path\to\output.csv -notype
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!